# How to retrieve all commits, committer and commit time for a complete project?

Tags: git, github

Is there any way to get the commit data for a project as follows:

 commit1 committer commit_time

 commit2 committer commit_time

 commit3 committer commit_time
.
.
.

git shortlog only gives the number of commits by user and git log gives multiple statements for each individual commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `git log` for this purpose.  Something like:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%H %aN %ai" --all
```

Note: you said committer, but I think you mean author.  So the above shows the author name and time.  If you really mean committer, then you probably want this:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%H %cN %ci" --all
```

Look at the [`git-log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) man page in the "PRETTY FORMATS" section for more information on what options you can pass to format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this (with some nice coloring)

```
git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h %Cred%ad %Cgreen%ae %C(yellow)%s %Creset" --date=local
```

Take a good look at `git log --help` for more options and available fields

Comment: Add `--all` to bring commits from all branches.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
git log --pretty="format:%H %cn %cd"
```

Or, if you want the email instead of the name:

```
git log --pretty="format:%H %ce %cd"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract a whole bunch of information from git log using formatting options describes in git commit history page. for your requirement you can do something like this

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h - %cn, %cd"
```

have a look on this [page](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History) for more options