# How do you retrieve all commits, committer and commit time for a complete project in SVN?

Tags: svn

Is there any way to get the commit data for a SVN project as follows:

commit1 committer commit_time

commit2 committer commit_time

commit3 committer commit_time

.

.

.

The solution for GIT is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939790/how-to-retrieve-all-commits-committer-and-commit-time-for-a-complete-project)! Need something similar for SVN

Answer (score 0):

`svn log` will accomplish this for you:

```
C:\Code>svn help log

log: Show the log messages for a set of revision(s) and/or path(s).
usage: 1. log [PATH][@REV]
       2. log URL[@REV] [PATH...]

  1. Print the log messages for the URL corresponding to PATH
     (default: '.'). If specified, REV is the revision in which the
     URL is first looked up, and the default revision range is REV:1.
     If REV is not specified, the default revision range is BASE:1,
     since the URL might not exist in the HEAD revision.

  2. Print the log messages for the PATHs (default: '.') under URL.
     If specified, REV is the revision in which the URL is first
     looked up, and the default revision range is REV:1; otherwise,
     the URL is looked up in HEAD, and the default revision range is
     HEAD:1.

  Multiple '-c' or '-r' options may be specified (but not a
  combination of '-c' and '-r' options), and mixing of forward and
  reverse ranges is allowed.

  With -v, also print all affected paths with each log message.
  With -q, don't print the log message body itself (note that this is
  compatible with -v).

  Each log message is printed just once, even if more than one of the
  affected paths for that revision were explicitly requested.  Logs
  follow copy history by default.  Use --stop-on-copy to disable this
  behavior, which can be useful for determining branchpoints.

  The --depth option is only valid in combination with the --diff option
  and limits the scope of the displayed diff to the specified depth.

  Examples:
    svn log
    svn log foo.c
    svn log bar.c@42
    svn log http://www.example.com/repo/project/foo.c
    svn log http://www.example.com/repo/project foo.c bar.c
    svn log http://www.example.com/repo/project@50 foo.c bar.c

Valid options:
  -r [--revision] ARG      : ARG (some commands also take ARG1:ARG2 range)
                             A revision argument can be one of:
                                NUMBER       revision number
                                '{' DATE '}' revision at start of the date
                                'HEAD'       latest in repository
                                'BASE'       base rev of item's working copy
                                'COMMITTED'  last commit at or before BASE
                                'PREV'       revision just before COMMITTED
  -q [--quiet]             : print nothing, or only summary information
  -v [--verbose]           : print extra information
  -g [--use-merge-history] : use/display additional information from merge
                             history
  -c [--change] ARG        : the change made in revision ARG
  --targets ARG            : pass contents of file ARG as additional args
  --stop-on-copy           : do not cross copies while traversing history
  --incremental            : give output suitable for concatenation
  --xml                    : output in XML
  -l [--limit] ARG         : maximum number of log entries
  --with-all-revprops      : retrieve all revision properties
  --with-no-revprops       : retrieve no revision properties
  --with-revprop ARG       : retrieve revision property ARG
  --depth ARG              : limit operation by depth ARG ('empty', 'files',
                             'immediates', or 'infinity')
  --diff                   : produce diff output
  --diff-cmd ARG           : use ARG as diff command
  --internal-diff          : override diff-cmd specified in config file
  -x [--extensions] ARG    : Default: '-u'. When Subversion is invoking an
                             external diff program, ARG is simply passed along
                             to the program. But when Subversion is using its
                             default internal diff implementation, or when
                             Subversion is displaying blame annotations, ARG
                             could be any of the following:
                                -u (--unified):
                                   Output 3 lines of unified context.
                                -b (--ignore-space-change):
                                   Ignore changes in the amount of white space.
                                -w (--ignore-all-space):
                                   Ignore all white space.
                                --ignore-eol-style:
                                   Ignore changes in EOL style.
                                -p (--show-c-function):
                                   Show C function name in diff output.

Global options:
  --username ARG           : specify a username ARG
  --password ARG           : specify a password ARG
  --no-auth-cache          : do not cache authentication tokens
  --non-interactive        : do no interactive prompting
  --trust-server-cert      : accept SSL server certificates from unknown
                             certificate authorities without prompting (but only
                             with '--non-interactive')
  --config-dir ARG         : read user configuration files from directory ARG
  --config-option ARG      : set user configuration option in the format:
                                 FILE:SECTION:OPTION=[VALUE]
                             For example:
                                 servers:global:http-library=serf
```

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, `svn log $REPO` will give you the entire history of the repository. You can use `-r` to specify whether you want this front to back or back to front:

```
$ svn -r1:HEAD $REPO   # Entire repository in chronological order.
$ svn -rHEAD:1 $REPO   # Entire repository in reverse chronological order
```

This won't get you the output you desired. Instead, you'll have to use some programming to take this result and parse it. Here's an example:

```
svn log -r1:HEAD $REPO \
    | awk '/^-{72}/ {getline; print $0}' \
    | while IFS="|" read revision author date junk
do
    echo "Author = '$author'  Revision = '$revision' Date = '$date'"
done
```

This will print out:

```
Author = ' Bob '  Revision = 'r1233 '  Date = ' 2013-11-08 09:18:17 -0500 (Fri, 08 Nov 2013) '
```

Note the extra spaces around Author and Date and how Revision starts with an `r` and has a trailing space. Plus Date is pretty long and convoluted. However, it shouldn't be too difficult to clean up the data and print out the report you want.

Another thing you can do is to add the `--xml` parameter to the `svn log` command. That will get you an XML based output that can easily be parsed by Perl, PHP, Ruby, or Python:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
<logentry
     revision="1">
<author>Bob</author>
<date>2013-11-13T19:08:19.154858Z</date>
<msg>What I was doing</msg>
</logentry>
<logentry.../>
</log>
```

And, Python and Perl have modules that can pull out this information in a more pragmatic fashion too, so you don't have to use the XML output.